# Symfony - Two forms from two entities on the same page

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I want two forms on my home page, from two entities, in the same controller.

The  forms are the following :

```
class DevisController extends Controller
{
    public function DevisAction(Request $request)
    {
        $devis = new Devis();
        $form = $this->createForm(new DevisType(), $devis);

        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($devis);
            $em->flush();
            $request
                ->getSession()
                ->getFlashBag()
                ->add('info', 'Le devis a bien été envoyé !');

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
            $imgUrl = $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/419370oah.png'));

            $message
                ->setSubject('Demande de devis bien reçue !')
                ->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($devis->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'OAHDevisBundle:Devis:devis_email.html.twig',
                        array('url' => $imgUrl)
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message); 

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                 ->setSubject('Nouvelle demande de devis')
                 ->setFrom('xxxn@gmail.com')
                 ->setTo('xxxn@gmail.com')
                 ->setBody(
                      $this->renderView(
                           'OAHDevisBundle:Devis:devis_recu.html.twig'
                      ),
                      'text/html'
                 );

           $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oah_core_homepage'));
      }

      // Si on n'est pas en POST, alors on affiche le formulaire
      return $this->render('OAHCoreBundle:Core:layout.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
      ));
    }

    public function NewsletterAction(Request $request)
    {
        $newsletter = new Newsletter();
        $formEmail = $this->createForm(new NewsletterType(), $newsletter);

        if ($formEmail->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newsletter);
            $em->flush();

            $request
               ->getSession()
               ->getFlashBag()
               ->add('info', 'Vous êtes bien inscrit à la newsletter ');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oah_core_homepage'));
        } 

         return $this->render('OAHCoreBundle:Core:layout.html.twig', array(
            'formEmail' => $formEmail->createView(),
         ));
    }
}
```

The first works perfectly, and for the second I changed the variable name to make the difference for twig.
So in my template I have for the second:

```
{{ form(formEmail) }}
```

And each time I've the following error :

> Variable "formEmail" does not exist in
>   OAHCoreBundle:Core:layout.html.twig at line 384

What is wrong with this please?

Comment: Did you render  `OAHCoreBundle:Core:layout.html.twig` with `formEmail`? Are you referring to `NewsletterAction`?

Comment: I edited to show my whole controller

Comment: I think you are supposed to create both forms in the same method. Your current code shows you are only running one form.

Comment: i run two differents forms in my controller and show them in the template with form(form) and form(FormEmail). But formEmail doesn't exist

Comment: You can only call one controller action. When calling `DevisAction` you are not even touching the `NewsletterAction` and that's why the error

Comment: So i have to create all the form in the same action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your current code, you are only calling your `DevisAction`.

While doing that, you are not even touching the `NewsletterAction` and that's why your twig cannot find the `formEmail` form.

Try including both your forms in one controller action like this and it should render properly.

```
class DevisController extends Controller
{
    public function DevisAction(Request $request)
    {
        $devis = new Devis();
        $form = $this->createForm(new DevisType(), $devis);

        $newsletter = new Newsletter();
        $formEmail = $this->createForm(new NewsletterType(), $newsletter);

        if ($formEmail->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newsletter);
            $em->flush();

            $request
                ->getSession()
                ->getFlashBag()
                ->add('info', 'Vous êtes bien inscrit à la newsletter ');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oah_core_homepage'));
        }

        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($devis);
            $em->flush();
            $request
                ->getSession()
                ->getFlashBag()
                ->add('info', 'Le devis a bien été envoyé !');

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
            $imgUrl = $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/419370oah.png'));

            $message
                ->setSubject('Demande de devis bien reçue !')
                ->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($devis->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'OAHDevisBundle:Devis:devis_email.html.twig',
                        array('url' => $imgUrl)
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Nouvelle demande de devis')
                ->setFrom('xxxn@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('xxxn@gmail.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'OAHDevisBundle:Devis:devis_recu.html.twig'
                    ),
                    'text/html'
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oah_core_homepage'));
        }

        // Si on n'est pas en POST, alors on affiche le formulaire
        return $this->render('OAHCoreBundle:Core:layout.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'formEmail' => $formEmail->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

**EDIT** This still needs to be cleaned by providing proper form validation which I have not done but the rendering problem should be solved.