# symfony3: form action not working (and happy for it)

Tags: php, zurb-foundation, symfony

I'm making a fairly large symfony3 application. It's my first one and I must say I'm pretty amazed by the robustness of the framework. It's an application that lets users create "events". And every event is happening in a certain "location". I have two bundles "EventBundle" and "VenueBundle". A venue can host many events so there's a one to many relation between the two. At this point I have an event creation page with a dropdown input that is automaticly filled with the venues already in the database. The EntityType field made it easy for me to implement that relation. This is an awesome symfony feature.

Because it's possible that not every venue is already in the database at the moment of creating a new event, I want to use a small "quick create venue" modal window (based on zurb-foundation) in the event creation wizard. It's to prevent users from exiting the wizard to add a new venue.

I was struggeling for the past two or three days or so to have two forms from different entities on one twig page. I have already found the answer in this question: [Symfony - Two forms from two entities on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049256/symfony-two-forms-from-two-entities-on-the-same-page). But the answer raised a second question for me. I think it's easier to explain if I first show the code I'm having right now:

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $event = new Event();
    $eventForm = $this->createForm(EventType::class, $event);

    $venue = new Venue();
    $venueQuickForm = $this->createForm(VenueQuickType::class, $venue, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('massiv_venue_quickcreate')
    ));

    $eventForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($eventForm->isSubmitted() && $eventForm->isValid()) {
        $event = $eventForm->getData();

        $event->setPostedBy(1);
        $event->setUpdatedBy(1);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('massiv_event_homepage');
    }

    $venueQuickForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($venueQuickForm->isSubmitted() && $venueQuickForm->isValid()) {
        $venue = $venueQuickForm->getData();

        $venue->setPostedBy(1);
        $venue->setUpdatedBy(1);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($venue);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

In the createForm method of the second form (venueQuickForm) I added the option "action" with a url pointing to the venue controller's quickcreate action. That was my idea, I had this already in my code before I found the answer, but kept that line to see how it would behave. It turns out it is ignored because in that quickCreateAction method I simply put a "ok" response and that page is not shown when a press the submit button. The rest of the code works fine, the venue is saved in the database.

So I am about to delete that line, but is the code above indeed the way to go? Intuitively I want to keep both codes seperate so putting the "save venue" part in the Venue controller seems locic to me or is that not the way Symfony is designed to work?